# How to sort NSarray in Sections for UITableview

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview

Hi how can I sort my Array in sections by Day , I get the data form my webserver (Json) and parse to NSDictionary then save to NSMutableArray... I understand I need to implement

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
- titleForHeaderInSection:
- Row for Section:

NSMutableArray Log

```
2012-04-26 06:12:51.256 passingdata[91699:fb03] array : (
{
post =         {
    "CLASS_LEVEL" = "Intro/General";
    "CLASS_TYPE" = "Muay Thai";
    "DAY_OF_WEEK" = Sunday;
    ID = 19;
    "ORDER_BY" = 5;
    TIME = "1:00pm - 2:30pm";
};
}
{
post =         {
    "CLASS_LEVEL" = "General/Intermediate/Advanced";
    "CLASS_TYPE" = "Muay Thai Spar - Competitive";
    "DAY_OF_WEEK" = Friday;
    ID = 27;
    "ORDER_BY" = 5;
    TIME = "6:00pm - 9:00pm";
};
},
{
post =         {
    "CLASS_LEVEL" = "Fighters/Advanced/Intermediate";
    "CLASS_TYPE" = "Fighters Training";
    "DAY_OF_WEEK" = Monday;
    ID = 1;
    "ORDER_BY" = 1;
    TIME = "9:30am - 11:00pm";
};
},
```

I can Display all the Data on my table , but I want to do it by section for each day (mon ,tue , wed.. sun), I have try NSpredicate and NSSet but still not working .

I don't know how to group items by day and get all the information to implement all the methods.

Any ideas ?? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using the [NSPredicate](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPredicate_Class/Reference/NSPredicate.html) class.

This is what you should do:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"DAY_OF_WEEK MATCHES %@",@"Monday"];
NSArray *sections = [tableData filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

The predicate format should not hardcode the day, but should loop through all days and create arrays with results for each day.

Comment: but do I need one NSPredicate for each Day ?

Comment: like I told you, you should loop through the days to filter in the numberOfSectionsInTableView, or create an array with the items per day. Which approach to choose is up to you.

Comment: I can do the predicate for each day but how do I get the information from all the the Array's (MonArray ... SunArray.), thanks for your help I am very new to Programming .. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use NSSortdiscriptor code use this line of code.

```
 NSSortDescriptor *timeSD = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey: @"time" ascending: YES];
 NSMutableArray *sortedByTime = [UnsortedArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors: timeSD];
 NSMutableArray *sortedArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[sortedByTime count]];
```

Answer (score 0):

use this approach

```
- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
{
   NSMutableSet *mySet = [[[NSMutableSet alloc] init] autorelease];
   for ( NSString *s in myArray )
   {
     if ( s.length > 0 )
       [mySet addObject:[s substringToIndex:1]];
   }

   NSArray *indexArray = [[mySet allObjects] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
   return indexArray;
}
```

Comment: Error at this line NSArray *indexArray = [[mySet allObjects]..... [NSmutable count] : Method sent to an uninitialized mutable set Object .. thanks

Comment: if this array occers then u have not used init with your mySet declration statment

Comment: sorry .. i forgot init I am using (ARC) .. i'll try later thanks

Answer (score 0):

This method is the simplest way to do your job:

```
NSArray *sortedStrings = [strings sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
```

More about:[sortedArrayUsingSelector](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html)